# Как лучше сделать подсветку курсора?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возникла потребность сделать как бы подсветку курсора на кнопках. То-бишь, чтоб когда провожу им по кнопке, то под курсором был какой-то градиент, фон, кружок.. что- не очень важно.

Вопрос вот в чём: как это лучше реализовать? Перемещать что-то на самом фоне кнопки или просто создать прозрачный блок с бекграундом и перемещать уже его?

Comment: можно просто поменять курсор

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Мы не ищем лёгких путей!

```js
var curBg = document.querySelectorAll('.cur-bg'),
  mouseBg = document.getElementById('mouse-bg');

for (var i = 0; i < curBg.length; i++) {
  curBg[i].addEventListener('mousemove', foo, false);
  curBg[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', boo, false);
}

function foo(event) {
  mouseBg.style.display = 'block';
  mouseBg.style.left = (event.clientX - 7) + 'px'
  mouseBg.style.top = (event.clientY - 7) + 'px'
}

function boo() {
  mouseBg.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
  #mouse-bg {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #41bd9d, #d72222);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-animation: AnimationName 1s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: AnimationName 1s ease infinite;
  animation: AnimationName 1s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {background-position: 0% 50%}
  50% {background-position: 100% 50%}
  100% {background-position: 0% 50%}
}

@-o-keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {background-position: 0% 50%}
  50% {background-position: 100% 50%}
  100% {background-position: 0% 50%}
}

@keyframes AnimationName {
  0% {background-position: 0% 50%}
  50% {background-position: 100% 50%}
```

```html
<input class="cur-bg" type="button" value="button" />
<button class="cur-bg">button</button>
<span class="cur-bg">button</span>

<div id="mouse-bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Самое простое - нарисовать png-шку и подменять ею внешний вид курсора при ховере на кнопке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
button {
 padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRS91.png"), default;
}
```

```html
<button>
КНОПКА
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы!

По примеру Kirill Korushkin сделал следующее:

(без использования class)

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";
 var EX = function (f1, f2) {
  /**упрощение работы с get и set.
  возвращает {get:function(){return f1;},set:f2},
  если f2=true, то set:f1, если f2 нет, то set:undefined
   **/
  return {
   get: function () {
    return f1;
   },
   set: f2 === true ? f1 : f2 || undefined
  };
 };
 EX.auto = function (f1, f2) {
  /**тоже упрощает работу с get и set.
  возвращает:
  если f2=setget, EX(f1,true)
  если f2=set, {set:f1}
  если f2=get, {get:function(){return f1;}}
  если f2=что-то-другое, {get:f1}
   **/

  switch (f2) {
  case "setget":
   return EX(f1, !!1);
  case "set":
   return {
    set: fl
   };
  case "get":
   return {
    get: function () {
     return f1;
    }
   };
  default:
   return {
    get: f1
   }
  }
 };
 Object.defineProperties(Object.prototype, {
  Ainit: {
   /**конструктор объектов.
   принимает объект и помещает его свойства в тот, на котором вызван Init.
   если объект содержит конструкции типа l:{set:...,get:...}(только как прямые потомки), то они будут использованы как get l или set l (isEnumerable,isConfigurable,isWritable).
   если свойство __isParam__ установлено в false l:{__isParam__:false}, то все свойства будут приниматься НЕ как параметры свойствa l (enumerable,configurable,writable,get,set)
   также get и set можно создать, используя имя самой функции l:function get(){}-
   get - создаст get с обёрткой
   l:{
   get:function (){
   return get(){};
   }
   } - функция не будет выполняться сама
   set - создаст set
   setget - создаст set и get для одной функции
   auto- создаст get без обёртки функции(она выполнится сама при вызове get)
    **/
   enumerable: false,
   configurable: false,
   writable: true,
   value: function (vl) {
    var tmp = {};
    for (var nm in vl) {
     var s = vl[nm] || {},
     isp = s.__isParam__,
     sn = s.name || "";
     delete s.__isParam__;
     tmp[nm] = (s.set === undefined && s.get === undefined && s.enumerable === undefined && s.configurable === undefined && s.writable === undefined && ["get", "auto", "setget", "set"].indexOf(sn) === -1 && isp !== true) || isp === false ? {
      enumerable: false,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: vl[nm]
     }
      : (s.constructor !== Function ? s : EX.auto(s, sn));
    }
    Object.defineProperties(this, tmp);
   }
  }
 });
 var cp, //cursor position
 whp = {}, //width, height, position, css position, this
 dsp,
 gtc, //styles
 rect, 
 win,
 sensor = !!("ontouchmove" in document), //проверка на сенсор
 newElem = function (attrs, statics) { //используется вместо class для создания элементов
  function felement() {
   return Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], felement);
  }
  Object.setPrototypeOf(felement.prototype, HTMLElement.prototype);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(felement, HTMLElement);

  felement.prototype.Ainit(attrs);
  felement.Ainit(statics);

  return felement;
 },
 offset = {},
 getProps = function (th) {
    offset = th.getBoundingClientRect();
  gtc = getComputedStyle(th);
  return {
   w: parseFloat(gtc.width),
   h: parseFloat(gtc.height),
   p: {top:offset.top,left:offset.left},
   f: gtc.position === "fixed",
   e: th
  };
 };
 window.elems = []; //все элементы подсветки
 !sensor && document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  cp = {
   t: event.clientY,
   l: event.clientX
  };
  elems.forEach(function (th) {
   whp = getProps(th[0]);
   whp.b = getProps(th[1]);
   dsp = {
    l: whp.e.getAttribute("b-left-despos"),
    t: whp.e.getAttribute("b-top-despos")
   };
   dsp.t ? (
    dsp.t = Function("it,cursor", "return " + dsp.t)(whp, cp)) : (
    dsp.t = cp.t - whp.b.h / 2 - whp.p.top //выравнивание центра элемента
   );

   dsp.l ? (
    dsp.l = Function("it,cursor", "return " + dsp.l)(whp, cp)) : (
    dsp.l = cp.l - whp.b.w / 2 - whp.p.left);

   whp.b.e.style.left = dsp.l + "px";
   whp.b.e.style.top = dsp.t + "px";
  });
 });
 customElements.define("f-dplane", newElem({
   connectedCallback: function () {
    if (sensor) {
     this.setAttribute("sensor", "");
     return;
    }
    var back = document.createElement("div");
    back.setAttribute("b", "");
    back.style.top = "200%";
    back.style.left = "200%";
    this.appendChild(back);
    elems.push([this, back]);
   },
   disconnectedCallback: function () {
    var elem,
    th = this;
    elems.forEach(function (el, ind) {
     if (el[0] === th) {
      elem = ind;
     }
    });
    elems.splice(elem, 1);
   }
  }));
})();
```

```css
/*f-dplane default*/
f-dplane:not([sensor]){
 cursor:default;
 display:flex;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
f-dplane:not([sensor]) div{
 position:absolute;
 background:radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13),transparent,transparent) no-repeat;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}

/*other*/
.gg{
  width:400px;
  height:50px;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  background:black;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  color:white;
}
.gg > f-dplane {
  top:0;
}
.gg > f-dplane > [b] {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
```

Количество кода на js можно уменьшить почти в 2 раза, если использовать class:

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";
 var cp, //cursor position
 whp = {}, //width, height, position, css position, this
 dsp,
 gtc, //styles
 rect,
 win,
 sensor = !!("ontouchmove" in document), //проверка на сенсор
 offset = {},
 getProps = function (th) {
    offset = th.getBoundingClientRect();
  gtc = getComputedStyle(th);
  return {
   w: parseFloat(gtc.width),
   h: parseFloat(gtc.height),
   p: {top:offset.top,left:offset.left},
   f: gtc.position === "fixed",
   e: th
  };
 };
 window.elems = []; //все элементы подсветки
 !sensor && document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  cp = {
   t: event.clientY,
   l: event.clientX
  };
  elems.forEach(function (th) {
   whp = getProps(th[0]);
   whp.b = getProps(th[1]);
   dsp = {
    l: whp.e.getAttribute("b-left-despos"),
    t: whp.e.getAttribute("b-top-despos")
   };
   dsp.t ? (
    dsp.t = Function("it,cursor", "return " + dsp.t)(whp, cp)) : (
    dsp.t = cp.t - whp.b.h / 2 - whp.p.top //выравнивание центра элемента
   );

   dsp.l ? (
    dsp.l = Function("it,cursor", "return " + dsp.l)(whp, cp)) : (
    dsp.l = cp.l - whp.b.w / 2 - whp.p.left);

   whp.b.e.style.left = dsp.l + "px";
   whp.b.e.style.top = dsp.t + "px";
  });
 });
 class fdplane extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback() {
   if (sensor) {
    this.setAttribute("sensor", "");
    return;
   }
   var back = document.createElement("div");
   back.setAttribute("b", "");
   back.style.top = "200%";
   back.style.left = "200%";
   this.appendChild(back);
   elems.push([this, back]);
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
   var elem,
   th = this;
   elems.forEach(function (el, ind) {
    if (el[0] === th) {
     elem = ind;
    }
   });
   elems.splice(elem, 1);
  }
 }
 customElements.define("f-dplane", fdplane);
})();
```

```css
/*f-dplane default*/
f-dplane:not([sensor]){
 cursor:default;
 display:flex;
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
f-dplane:not([sensor]) div{
 position:absolute;
 background:radial-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13),transparent,transparent) no-repeat;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}

/*other*/
.gg{
  width:400px;
  height:50px;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  background:black;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  color:white;
}
.gg > f-dplane {
  top:0;
}
.gg > f-dplane > [b] {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class="gg">
  <f-dplane></f-dplane>
  asdasdasd
</button>
```